# How to extend my multiple loop conditions?

Tags: c

My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=0;
int j=0;
size_t count=0;
float numbers[20][100];
float velocity[21][101];
char *line = NULL;

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("vel.txt", "r");

    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

while(i < 20 && getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) {
int len = 0, pos = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(j < 100 && 1 == sscanf(line + pos, "%f%n", &numbers[i][j++], &len))
        pos += len;
    i++;
}
free(line); 
fclose(myFile);

    i=1;
    for( j = 0; j < 101; j++ )
    {
       if( j == 1 )
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];  
       }
       else if ( j == 101 )
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];   
       }  
       else
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i][j-1]+numbers[i][j])/2;       
       }    
    }

      for (j=0 ; j<101 ; j++) {
        printf("\n%f",  velocity[i][j]);
      }   
}
```

I need to calculate velocities for 21,101 two dimensional mesh.If `i==1` ,that is my code above and works fine.The sam conditions apply if `i==21`.But for all other values (2 to 20) calculations are different.How should I change

```
if( i== from 2 to 20 &&j == 1 )
       {
       do something 
       }
       else if (i== from to to 20 && j == 101 )
       {
       do something 2   
       }  
       else(means i goes from 2,20 j goes from 2,100)
       {
       do something 3   
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this: `if(i >= 2 %% i <= 20)`? Means: 2 <= i <= 20 or if i is greater or the same as 2 and i is lower or the same as 20 it is true.

If your example:

```
if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j == 1)
{
    //do something
}
else if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j == 101)
{
    //do something 2
}
else if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j >= 2 && j <= 100) //means i goes from 2,20 j goes from 2,100
{
    //do something 3
}
```

or is there anything I missed?

Comment: No,this can not be compiled,take a look at else,how should this look like in case of two variables?